# What Fitting is This?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gas

This is on a propane tabletop flame. This is the input. The thread pitch is 18/inch and the major diameter is .525 inches measured.

I can thread a 1/4 NPT onto this, but this is not tapered.

[image: fitting]

[image: fitting zoom]

[image: fitting measured]

Comment: NPTF has 18 TPI, are you certain about the diameter?

Comment: looks like a compression fitting to me.

Comment: Added a pic showing the diameter.

Comment: 1/4 NPS. T for tapered, S for straight.

Comment: As commented; a compression fitting, notice the shoulder on the ID. Proprietary , so you must use the same product if you want a seal.

Comment: I think NPS is correct. Had to get this by Xmas, so I put an NPT on it with lots of thread sealant.